# Ubuntu One can't connect

Tags: ubuntu-one

I'm trying to upload a file to my Ubuntu One cloud, but when I open the Ubuntu One Control Panel on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine, it notifies me that "File Sync is disconnected."

So, naturally, I'll click the "Connect" button next to it, and it will say "File Sync in progress..." and it will want to upload my file, but it doesn't seem like anything is happening. Then, after a minute, it will simply regress into "File Sync is disconnected." This, of course, frustrates me greatly, and causes me to wonder, what could I possibly be doing wrong?

I have already tried `u1sdtool -q`, `u1sdtool --status`, and `u1sdtool --start`
the status report is :

```
> u1sdtool --status
State: WAITING
    connection: With User With Network
    description: waiting before try connecting again
    is_connected: False
    is_error: False
    is_online: False
    queues: WORKING
```

Although I am able to add or remove devices from both web service as well as UbuntuOne on my desktop running Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: There is a problem with the file sync servers at the moment and it is being investigated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the same problem posted here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/423784/ubuntu-one-disconnects-after-a-few-seconds

maybe the authentication server has a temporally problem.

details from status.log:

```
2014-02-20 20:56:57,621 - ubuntuone.status - DEBUG - server connection lost
2014-02-20 20:58:57,695 - ubuntuone.status - DEBUG - server connection made
2014-02-20 20:58:58,118 - ubuntuone.status - DEBUG - server connection lost
...
```

details from syncdaemon.log:

```
2014-02-20 21:00:58,126 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.ActionQueue - INFO - Connection started to host fs-1.one.ubuntu.com, port 443.
2014-02-20 21:00:58,168 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.ActionQueue - INFO - Connection made.
2014-02-20 21:00:58,169 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.StorageClient - INFO - Connection made.
2014-02-20 21:00:58,412 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.ActionQueue - INFO - The request 'protocol_version' finished OK.
2014-02-20 21:00:58,690 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.ActionQueue - INFO - The request 'caps_raising_if_not_accepted' finished OK.
2014-02-20 21:00:58,931 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.ActionQueue - INFO - The request 'caps_raising_if_not_accepted' finished OK.
2014-02-20 21:00:59,138 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.ActionQueue - INFO - The request 'oauth_authenticate' failed with the error: TRY_AGAIN and was handled with the event: SYS_SERVER_ERROR
2014-02-20 21:00:59,139 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.StorageClient - INFO - Connection lost, reason: [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion: Connection lost.
].
2014-02-20 21:00:59,140 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.ActionQueue - WARNING - Connection lost: Connection was closed cleanly.
```

details from credentials.log:

```
2014-02-20 21:08:42,870 - ubuntuone.credentials - DEBUG - login: args (<ubuntuone.platform.credentials.CredentialsManagementTool object at 0xaaf734c>,), kwargs {'window_id': 0}.
2014-02-20 21:08:43,213 - ubuntuone.credentials - INFO - Starting Ubuntu One login manager for bus 'com.ubuntuone.Credentials'.
2014-02-20 21:08:43,217 - ubuntuone.credentials - DEBUG - ref_count is 0, changing value to 1.
2014-02-20 21:08:43,522 - ubuntuone.credentials - DEBUG - Handling DBus signal for member: 'CredentialsFound', app_name: dbus.String(u'Ubuntu One').
2014-02-20 21:08:43,522 - ubuntuone.credentials - INFO - 'CredentialsFound'
2014-02-20 21:08:43,522 - ubuntuone.credentials - DEBUG - ref_count is 1, changing value to 0.
2014-02-20 21:08:43,522 - ubuntuone.credentials - DEBUG - Setting up timer with <function timeout_add at 0xb6af6c6c> (10000, <bound method CredentialsManagement.shutdown of <ubuntuone.platform.credentials.dbus_service.CredentialsManagement at /credentials at 0x9af08cc>>).
2014-02-20 21:08:43,523 - ubuntuone.credentials - INFO - CredentialsManagement: emitting CredentialsFound.
2014-02-20 21:08:43,524 - ubuntuone.credentials - DEBUG - cleanup: removing signal match <<class 'dbus.connection.SignalMatch'> at a7eaa4c "type='signal',sender='com.ubuntuone.Credentials',path='/credentials',interface='com.ubuntuone.CredentialsManagement',member='CredentialsFound'" on conn <dbus._dbus.SessionBus (session) at 0xa98d4dc>>
2014-02-20 21:08:43,524 - ubuntuone.credentials - DEBUG - cleanup: removing signal match <<class 'dbus.connection.SignalMatch'> at a7ea44c "type='signal',sender='com.ubuntuone.Credentials',path='/credentials',interface='com.ubuntuone.CredentialsManagement',member='AuthorizationDenied'" on conn <dbus._dbus.SessionBus (session) at 0xa98d4dc>>
2014-02-20 21:08:43,524 - ubuntuone.credentials - DEBUG - cleanup: removing signal match <<class 'dbus.connection.SignalMatch'> at a7ea86c "type='signal',sender='com.ubuntuone.Credentials',path='/credentials',interface='com.ubuntuone.CredentialsManagement',member='CredentialsError'" on conn <dbus._dbus.SessionBus (session) at 0xa98d4dc>>
2014-02-20 21:08:53,533 - ubuntuone.credentials - DEBUG - shutdown!, ref_count is 0.
2014-02-20 21:08:53,533 - ubuntuone.credentials - INFO - Shutting down, calling <gi.FunctionInfo object (quit) at 0x0x9af0780>.
```